# Почему вложенный цикл foreach принимает от основного одно и тоже значение?

Tags: php, массивы, циклы

Мне нужно отсортировать все нечетные цифры в массиве по возрастанию, четные цифры оставить на своих местах.
**Выполнил следующее:**

1. создал функцию принимающую массив;
2. в функции создал пустой массив для нечетных чисел;
3. форычем пробежался по массиву, вместо нечетных чисел воткнул заглушки -> " ! ", а их значения поместил в массив для нечетных чисел;
4. отсортировал массив нечетных чисел по возрастанию;
5. форычем начал проходить по массиву с нечетными числами и в нем запустил второй форыч для того чтобы вместо заглушек воткнуть значения отсортированного массива.

Но на выходе получается что вместо заглушек вставляется одно и то же значение.

[image: Результат работы функции]

Код:

```
function debug($arr)
{
    echo "<pre>" . print_r($arr, 1) . "</pre>";
}

function odd_sort (array $arr): array
{
  $oddArr = [];

  foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
  {
      if ($value % 2 == 1){
          $oddArr[] = $value;
          $arr[$key] = "!";
      }
  }

  sort($oddArr);

  foreach ($oddArr as $oddValue){
   
      foreach ($arr as $key =>  $value) if ($value == "!") $arr[$key] = $oddValue;
   
  }
  return $arr;
  }

  $nums = [5, 3, 2, 7, 8, 1, 4,];

  debug(odd_sort($nums));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если именно так нужно писать, тогда не хватает просто break

```
...
foreach ($arr as $key =>  $value) if ($value == "!") { $arr[$key] = $oddValue; break; }
...
```

Comment: не верно, то же самое на выходе

Comment: а нет, все работает, спасибо большое, а можете как-то подробнее объяснить ?

Comment: Потому что сразу после вложеного цикла, все заглушки ($arr[$key] = "!") найдены и заменены на 1, первый $oddValue.

Comment: Поэтому, как только найдена первая заглушка нужен break, чтобы выйти из вложенного цикла, для поиска следующей заглушки и т.д.